# Delay in getting the value in salesforce classic

Tags: salesforce

I need to update the commission field based on some calculations. I am using the future method to update the commission field. Commission field is getting updated immediately in lightening as expected. However, in salesforce classic, I need to refresh the page manually then only it reflects me the updated commission value.
Can someone please help me to provide the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm?search_text=future): 
"A future method runs in the background, asynchronously."

So.. your @Future method runs only when the server resources are free (after your trigger update ends).

I wonder if in lightning experience there's a refresh mechanism (like "rerender" or "$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()") that occurs when the operation finishes and this can explain why in Lightning you see the results without the need to update the page.

Comment: Hi Moshe, Thank you very much. This information really helps.